# Did localStorage just break in Firefox 6.0.2 on Mac?

Tags: javascript, firefox, local-storage, firefox6

I'm playing around with HTML5. For that purpose I created some small Javascript widget using localStorage amongst other things. Up until yesterday Firefox played nice.

Then 6.0.2 came around and suddenly the localStorage object is null.

Going to http://html5test.com shows that Local Storage is not supported.

[image]

Using Chrome to view the exact same code (found at http://scriptonomicon.dk/CCDashboard/index.html) works fine. Using Firefox 6.0.2 on Windows (7) works just fine.

Has anyone else experienced that localstorage is broken on Firefox 6.0.2 on Mac?

Comment: I do remember hearing that a security bug in the localstorage spec/implementation caused it to be dropped for a short time, in ff/chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the storage preferences, type `about:config` into the location bar. The relevant preferences are:

- `dom.storage.enabled` - should obviously be `true`
- `dom.storage.default_quota` - default value is `5120`

Comment: That's it! dom.storage.enabled was "user set" to false. Now the question remains how that happened. I certainly didn't set it. Thank you.

Comment: @erlando: If you had some "privacy protection" extension installed - that would be your prime suspect.

Comment: It went from "working" on 6.0.1 to "not-working" on 6.0.2. Only thing happening AFAIK was the update from .1 to .2 .

Comment: @erlando: That update definitely didn't change your preferences however, only changes happened in the certificates code.

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me:

[image: HTML5Test screenshot showing success]

Comment: Thank you. It would seem I have a local problem. How very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, on Firefox 6.0.2 on Windows.  Tried on two different PCs.  Gets weirder though, as the flags in about:config were set correctly and the html5test.com indicator said it's supported.  It definitely wasn't though - I spent 4 hours pulling my hair out at a simple implementation of setItem / getItem which just did not work.  Fine in Chrome.

In the end I think I have resolved it though.  Are you working locally on the filesystem by any chance?  Try working from a proper domain or setting up local DNS for a test domain locally - that has done the trick for me - it now works!