# Safari and Chrome do not want to JSON.parse

Tags: json, google-chrome, safari

I'm trying out localStorage and JSON using a variety of browsers with this piece of code:

```
        function getStorage() {
            stored = JSON.parse(localStorage['test']);
            if (typeof stored == 'object') {return stored;}
        }
```

Chrome gives me the following error message: **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u"** for the first line inside the function body. For that same line, Safari says **"SyntaxError: Unable to parse JSON string"**. Firefox does not give any error messages for that line.

Other JSON.parse examples (from books, etc) work fine in both Safari and Chrome. For instance, this one from "Pro JavaScript" by Nicholas Zakas:

```
            var jsonText = "{\"name\":\"Nicholas C. Zakas\", \"age\":29, \"author\":true }";
            var object = JSON.parse(jsonText);
            alert(object.name);  //"Nicholas C. Zakas"
```

No problem at all with getting that to work. Local storage also works fine in both.

I've also checked the encoding on all my files using `file -I my file` and all files, both my own and the ones from the above book, are encoded as `filename.html: text/html; charset=us-ascii` - so encoding doesn't seem to be the problem here.

This is perplexing. Thanks a lot for any help.

/ James

Comment: What is the data you are storing in the local storage? Seems not to be conform json.

Comment: can we see the json string that you are trying to parse?

Comment: Sure, here's the JSON string: `if (window.localStorage) {
    if (localStorage.length == 0) {
       json = {"test": ["foo", "bar"]} // json is a global variable
       window.localStorage.setItem("test", JSON.stringify(json));
    }
}`

Comment: Did you try to use console.log(localStorage["test"]) to check the value that is stored?

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks for the advice on debugging the contents of localStorage directly. The bug was in the line `if (localStorage.length == 0)`. I had some other data in localStorage from previous apps, so `json` didn't get set to anything inside that conditional. Now I use `if (!localStorage['test']) {//set json}`. So much for Safari & Chrome - in Firefox 6.0.2 localStorage isn't working for different reasons: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355324/did-localstorage-just-break-in-firefox-6-0-2-on-mac

Answer (score 0):

It's because the content of `localStorage['test']` is `undefined`, hence the unexpected `u`.

Answer (score -2):

> Thanks for the advice on debugging the contents of localStorage directly. The bug was in the line if (localStorage.length == 0). I had some other data in localStorage from previous apps, so json didn't get set to anything inside that conditional.